# Entity Framework mapping error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have following entities defined as:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.UserClaims = new List<UserClaim>();
        this.UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
        this.UserLogins = new List<UserLogin>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> Gender { get; set; }
    public long AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public partial class UserClaim    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public string ClaimValue { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And mappings as follows:

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.UserName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.FirstName)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.LastName)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.MiddleName)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.Email)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.PasswordHash)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.SecurityStamp)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.PhoneNumber)
            .HasMaxLength(25);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Users");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
        this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
        this.Property(t => t.MiddleName).HasColumnName("MiddleName");
        this.Property(t => t.Gender).HasColumnName("Gender");
        this.Property(t => t.AddressId).HasColumnName("AddressId");
        this.Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
        this.Property(t => t.EmailConfirmed).HasColumnName("EmailConfirmed");
        this.Property(t => t.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("PasswordHash");
        this.Property(t => t.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("SecurityStamp");
        this.Property(t => t.PhoneNumber).HasColumnName("PhoneNumber");
        this.Property(t => t.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasColumnName("PhoneNumberConfirmed");
        this.Property(t => t.TwoFactorEnabled).HasColumnName("TwoFactorEnabled");
        this.Property(t => t.LockoutEndDateUtc).HasColumnName("LockoutEndDateUtc");
        this.Property(t => t.LockoutEnabled).HasColumnName("LockoutEnabled");
        this.Property(t => t.AccessFailedCount).HasColumnName("AccessFailedCount");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.UserRoles)
            .WithMany(t => t.Users)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("UserUserRoles");
                    m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                    m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                });

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Address)
            .WithMany(t => t.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.AddressId);

        this.HasMany(t => t.UserClaims)
        .WithOptional(t => t.User)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
    }
}
```

And

```
public class UserClaimMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserClaim>
{
    public UserClaimMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("UserClaims");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.ClaimType).HasColumnName("ClaimType");
        this.Property(t => t.ClaimValue).HasColumnName("ClaimValue");
        this.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithMany(t => t.UserClaims)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);

    }
}
```

UserClaim table has foreign key on column "UserId". Database tables looks like as follows.
[image]

While running application I receive following error.
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

UserClaim_User_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'UserClaim_User_Source' in relationship 'UserClaim_User'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.
UserClaim_User_Target_UserClaim_User_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'Id' on entity 'UserClaim' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'User' in the referential constraint 'UserClaim_User'.

I tried changing mappings but couldn't resolve this error. Can somebody please help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Typically, when I'm using the fluent API to define a 1:n relationship, I only define it in one direction. I.e., either `HasRequired()` on `UserClaimMap` or `HasMany()` on `UserMap`. The issue _may_ be that it's attempting to create two relationships. That said, the error appears to be due to a data type conflict, even though both `User.Id`and `UserClaims.UserId` are set to `long` (`BigInt` in SQL's mapping).

Comment: @JeremyCaney: I tried removing HasMany() relationship from UserMap but no luck. Also Id and UserId data types are same so I am confused why should this error crop up.